# Эффект покачивания

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как сделать эффект покачивания на jquery или css как здесь при наведении на опцию http://www.bestprogramminglanguagefor.me/q ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.block{
  position: relative;  
}
.circle{  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.block:hover .circle{ 
  position: absolute; top: 0;
  -webkit-animation: anim 4s infinite;     
     animation: anim 4s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
   0% { top: 0; left: 50%; }
   50% { top: 40px;  left: 50%;}  
   100% { top: 0;  left: 50%;} 
}
@keyframes anim {
   0% { top: 0; left: 50%; }
   50% { top: 40px;  left: 50%;}  
   100% { top: 0;  left: 50%;} 
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```